# Checking for empty fields and disabling button

Tags: jquery

I'm checking for three text fields, and if empty, the submit button should not be clickable. If all three text fields are not empty, then (as you guessed) the submit button will be clickable.

```
//nameText, emailText, commentsText = text fields
//If fields are non-empty, disabled status = false
$(nameText, emailText, commentsText).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

//If fields are empty, disabled status = true
$(nameText, emailText, commentsText).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

This isn't exactly working. The button is constantly disabled, and doesn't get enabled even when the fields are filled. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You want to disable button if **all** fields are empty or **any** field is empty?

Comment: Button should be disabled if ANY field is empty.

Comment: Use `$('#submitButton').prop('disabled', $('nameText[value=""], emailText[value=""], commentsText[value=""]').length > 0));`

Comment: This doesn't work as you expect: `$(nameText, emailText, commentsText)`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis:

`if $(this).val() == "") {`

should read:

`if ($(this).val() == "") {`

This is the case for both of your conditions.

I'd also use a flag so that you only need to use the one loop:

```
var isValid = true;

$(nameText, emailText, commentsText).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "")
        isValid = false;
});

$('#submitButton').prop('disabled', !isValid);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, fixed it. But now, even when I enter all 3 fields, the button remains disabled.

Comment: Can you expand on the last part - Use the second each?

Answer (score 0):

You could check it using:

```
$('#submitButton').prop('disabled', function(){
    return !!$(nameText).add(emailText).add(commentsText).filter(function(){
       return !this.value.trim(); 
    }).length
});
```

Comment: It works as expected. Of course, you have to call it on input change event

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take a look at this code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
 
  checkFormValidity();
  
  $("#name,#email,#comment ").keyup(function(){
    checkFormValidity();
  });
  
  
  function checkFormValidity(){
    var allFilled = true;
    $("#name,#email,#comment").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
          allFilled = false;
      }
    });
    
    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', (!allFilled));
      
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" value="">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
     <br>
    Comments:<br>
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: wow...got -1 without explanation. Someone must be very new to SO.

Comment: Bumped it back up for ya (don't know who downvoted.) Will try this and get back to you.

Comment: It's weird. The button is clickable after the first field is filled, and then it stays clickable even when I delete the input.

Comment: as suggested by @A. Wolff `$(nameText, emailText, commentsText)` this doesn't work as expected. So avoid using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98800/discussion-between-homerboy-and-vijayp).